# Which option seems the clearest when setting up an event

Tags: checkboxes

I asked this on a preference test, the results were very close, too close to call in fact.

You're setting up an event on an app that let's you choose whether your guests can reply or buy tickets, which option do you think is the clearest

01[image]

02 [image]

Comment: With option #1 is the checkbox even necessary? Why would I need to check 'yes' and then hit the 'add tickets' button when I could just hit the button if I want tickets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue I see here, is that you're using radio buttons that look like checkboxes. In scenario 1, the user might deduce that they can only select one option since the are mutually exclusive. However, in scenario 2, it might be very well possible to add tickets *and* a reply option to your event.

[Nielsen Norman Group](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/checkboxes-vs-radio-buttons/) states in their guidelines for checkboxes and radio buttons:

> 4. Use standard visual representations. A checkbox should be a small square that has a checkmark or an X when selected. A radio button should be a small circle that has a solid circle inside it when selected.

Therefore, I would go with scenario 1 for your current design. However, when the radio buttons do indeed look like radio buttons, scenario 2 could be preferable because it conveys both options to the user at once. At scenario 1, a user might never know that replies would have been an option until it's too late.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Nr. 1 because Nr. 2 is very unclear in my opinion. 
But I would still use a different text to make it more clear. 
As for now : "Choose whether you want to add tickets to your event, they can be free or paid " is a bit interpretable ( With english as a second language I understand something like if I want to give tickets inside the event).

I would go with something like :
Activate if admission to your event is made with tickets ( free or paid ).
Use this option if admission to the event is made with tickets ( free or paid ).